# Cypress scrollIntoView() giving error while assertion

Tags: selenium, web, automation, cypress, assertion

while I using should('be.visible') assertion then if the element is not on the screen assertion is giving an error. So that's why I using scrollIntoView() but this time element comes on screen so scrollIntoView() cannot work as respected an giving error too.

I don't want to use 'exist' i need to use 'be.visible' assertion.

Last error thrown code, I leaving here as an example.

```
Then('click work order from the work order list {int}', (i) => {
    cy.xpath(`//div[contains(@class, 'workorder')] //div[contains(text(), '` + getWorkOrderWithNoAttachment(i) + ` /` + `')]`)
        .scrollIntoView()
        .should('be.visible', { setTimeout: 10000 })
        .click()
})
```

Comment: Please add the code you tired along with error that you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollIntoView) state that

> It is unsafe to chain further commands that rely on the subject after .scrollIntoView().

Considering this I assume the following test should fix your current error:

```js
Then('click work order from the work order list {int}', (i) => {
    cy.xpath(`//div[contains(@class, 'workorder')] //div[contains(text(), '` + getWorkOrderWithNoAttachment(i) + ` /` + `')]`)
        .as('workOrder')
    cy.get('@workOrder').scrollIntoView();
    cy.get('@workOrder').should('be.visible', { setTimeout: 10000 })
    cy.get('@workOrder').click()
})
```

Furthermore [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements#Actionability) state that `click()` already performs

> - Scroll the element into view.
> - Ensure the element is not hidden.

So you can safely use the following test to achieve the same result:

```js
Then('click work order from the work order list {int}', (i) => {
    cy.xpath(`//div[contains(@class, 'workorder')] //div[contains(text(), '` + getWorkOrderWithNoAttachment(i) + ` /` + `')]`)
    .click()
})
```